# C# working with Excel via COM: how to replace the whole workbook with another one?

Tags: c#, excel, com

I develop an application, that generates rich Excel file (report) with charts, data, etc.
My program now just saves generated result in a file and launches it:

```
byte[] reportBytes = getReport(...);
string reportFilename = "report.xls";

Excel.Application oXL;
Excel.Workbook oWB;

try
{
    oXL = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
    oWB = oXL.Workbooks[name];
    oWB.Close(false);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //
}                

File.WriteAllBytes(reportFilename, reportBytes);
Process.Start(reportFilename);
```

And in this code opened Excel workbook is closed and reopened (that causes blink) every time when i launch my app. 
I'd like to have Excel workbok opened due development process and get report updates dynamically  after each launch. I believe COM technology can do it.

I need to replace all content of opened workbook by one from another (temporary) .xls file. Could you give me working example please?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough. What I understand is that you want to replace the content of excel file from another. Why not simply copy-paste the file. If the previous file is necessary then just copy it in backup folder before overwriting with new one.

If what I am saying applies then please comment on my answer. I'll further look into the problem. And please explain the problem properly.

As far as the blinking problem is concerned, why not try this:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
app.Workbooks.Open(@"<FilePath>");
```

But this will launch Excel and you will have to close it manually.

To avoid blinking during opening and closing of excel file use oledb to write to excel. Here is a sample code:

```
string filePath = @"<FilePath>";
string connectionString = @"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0, Data Source={0}"; 
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
conn.ConnectionString = string.Format(connectionString, filePath);
conn.Open();
cmd.CommandText = "Insert into [Sheet1$] (a1,a2) values('5','e')";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: When i launch my app for the first time - it saves generated report to file and opened it in Excel. Then i close my app, change its code (debug) and launch again. It generates report, closes opened .xls if i didnt close it manually, saves to the same filename and opens again. This close-reopen causes short-term "blink" of Excel window. I'd like to avoid it and refresh all .xls content on the fly. >"Why not simply copy-paste the file" Because this produces the error "file aready in use".

Comment: So you mean to say that you launch and close application while keeping log file open? If it is so then I would recommend to use oledb to write data to excel. See my updated answer for sample code.

Comment: I dont have any log. My excel file is a report generated by C# code. And yes, i keep it open while closing, editing and relaunching my C# code due debugging. I'd very like to avoid write copier of all parts of Excel file (data in the sheets, charts, styles, etc).